# Passing a stream to Restfull Wcf

Tags: wcf, rest

I am passing a stream to rest full wcf service.I would be setting up this stream as a payload and not in the uri.In this case what would be my uri template..

my contract looks like this :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRjisProxyWcfService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "")]
    Stream Post(Stream inputStream);
}
```

**What would be my uri template?**

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx

Theoretically it can be anything. E.g.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRjisProxyWcfService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "AAA/")]
    Stream Post(Stream inputStream);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IRjisProxyWcfService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "AAA/BBB")]
    Stream Post(Stream inputStream);
}
```

However, when you are putting, the putting url should be baseurl/AAA (first case) or baseurl/AAA/BBB (in the second case).

Sriwantha Sri Aravinda

Answer (score 0):

Your URI template would be the empty string, just the way you have specified it.